# How to call a script within a script and parse arguments

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create a master script that will call multiple python scripts parsing the date variables start and end.

I have 4 scripts to call

```
DAY_Level_Extract1.py
DAY_Level_Extract2.py
MONTH_Level_Extract1.py
MONTH_Level_Extract2.py
```

and i need to pass the following for example which is then used in the script:

```
start = datetime.date( year = 2012, month = 6, day = 1 )
end = datetime.date( year = 2012, month = 6, day = 2 )
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should design your Python files to be usable as modules.  Then the master can import the functions it needs from the others, and call those functions with the desired arguments (like `start` and `end`).

Here is a tutorial about modules in Python.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

I have no idea what your "extract" functions do.  I'm going to imagine they extract some data from lines in a log file or something like that.

So, make a source file called "dayextract.py" and put day extracting functions in it:

```
def day_extract1(line, start, end):
    ... # do actual day extracting stuff here
def day_extract2(line, start, end):
    ... # do actual day extracting stuff here
```

Then, make a source file called "monthextract.py" and put month extracting functions in it:

```
def month_extract1(line, start, end):
    ... # do actual month extracting stuff here
def month_extract2(line, start, end):
    ... # do actual month extracting stuff here
```

Finally, make your main program that will do all the work.  Have it import the needed functions:

```
import datetime

from dayextract import day_extract1, day_extract2
from monthextract import month_extract1, month_extract2

start = datetime.date( year = 2012, month = 6, day = 1 )
end = datetime.date( year = 2012, month = 6, day = 2 )

with open("some_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        day_extract1(line, start, end)
        day_extract2(line, start, end)
        month_extract1(line, start, end)
        month_extract2(line, start, end)
```